How to set SFSymbol color for light & dark mode when used as Button label in SwiftUI?
For an Image view acting as a label for a Button & displaying an SFSymbol like below, I'd like it to display with black foreground style for light mode and white for dark mode. I tried setting .foregroundStyle(.primary) but it doesn't work; the color of the icon stays blue. I know I could detect the light/dark colorScheme and implement the logic manually or create a Color in the asset catalog and use it but is there a way to automatically adapt Image  just as Text adapt to light & dark modes?
Button {
    
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    
}



An Image on its own does this already, and it will not be blue. Where are you putting the Image?

Ah, you're right. It's tinted since its used as the label for a Button. Work's fine when used as an Image. Updated the question to accurately reflect usage.

You can simply create a colorset in the Assets.xcassets

and use it like this.
    Button {
        
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "play.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .foregroundStyle(Color("imageColor"))
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
        
    }


Using Image as label for Button, Image is adapted default tint color of Button which is blue. So you can simple change tint of Button to the color you want:
Button {
    
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    
}
.tint(Color(UIColor.label)) // change tint color of Button


.tint(.primary) also works.
